# React Native - Expo - Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:237:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:317:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1215:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

[Print iphone expo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvB8Z.png)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Some additional context would be helpful in determining the best course of action.  This is pretty clearly an HTTP 400 Bad Request error, but we don't know much about the calling code, payload, or target service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of expo-cli. `npm i -g expo-cli`

Comment: what does `expo --version` return? it's possible that your global installation of `expo-cli` was done with yarn or some other node version and might be ahead in your path. if `expo-version` doesn't return the latest version from shown when you install it globally that is probably happening, and you might need to track down where that is coming from